# Expression Tree Member binding null with coalesce object?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, expression

I am trying to create an expression tree binding that will create an object if the property is available and place null if it is not. For example, I want to end up with:

```
personModel = car.Person == null ? null : new PersonModel()
```

But no matter what I try it fails.

I tried coalesce

```
Expression.Coalesce(
  Expression.Property(param, "Person"),
  Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(typeof(PersonModel)), MemberAssignment[])
)
```

This throws `System.ArgumentException: 'Argument types do not match'`. I assume the expression tree is expecting to place the same types in the coalesce - since I have a few nullable enumerates that work in the above scenario.

I tried conditional

```
Expression.Condition(
  Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, "Person"), Expression.Constant(null)),
  Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(typeof(PersonModel)), MemberAssignment[]),
  Expression.Constant(null)
)
```

This also throws `System.ArgumentException: 'Argument types do not match'` due to the true block having `Expresison.MemberInit` and the false block having `Expression.Constant`.

Is there anyway to make *something* like this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement `personModel = car.Person == null ? null : new PersonModel()` 
can be translated as:

```
 Expression.Condition(
 Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(car), "Person"), Expression.Constant(null,typeof(PersonModel))),
 Expression.Constant(null, typeof(PersonModel)), Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(typeof(PersonModel))));
```

Looks like what you missed to mention was the **typeof** for `null` constant as `Expression.Constant(null,typeof(PersonModel))`.

**Explanation:**

If you check the definition for `.Condition` it says it throws `System.ArgumentException`  when

> test.Type is not System.Boolean.-or-ifTrue.Type is not equal to
> ifFalse.Type

So, in your case , it is checking that the **Type** of values in both `false` and  `true` expression is `PersonModel`.
Compiler is able to conclude same for `false` (*new PersonModel()*) but not for `true` (*null*) so we need to explicitly state it.

Comment: Ah! Thanks @gkulshrestha! Any information on why we would need to specify the type of null?

Comment: @GrizzlyEnglish I added more details in my answer. Hope it helps.